# Bash: Moving multiple files into subfolders

Tags: bash, find, move

I have a folder with a couple thousand files and I want to move them into subfolders according to a string in the filename. The files all have a structure like

something-run1_001.txt

something-run22_1243.txt

So I tried the following script in order to move all files with "run1" in it into a subfolder r1 and all "run22" files in a subfolder r22 (and so on) but it does no work that way and I get a message "File X is the same as file X".

```
#!bin/bash

for i in {1..39}
do
foldername=r$i
#echo "$foldername"
mkdir $foldername
find . -type f -name "*run$i_*" | xargs -i mv {} $foldername/ 
done
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in {1..39}
do
  mkdir -p r${i}/
  mv *run${i}_* r${i}/
done
```

Comment: So easy... I tried something similar (but not the same) before and ran into the "too many arguments" trap.

Answer (score 1):

is this work as your requirement?

`mv *run*.html dir1`

Answer (score 0):

If you still run into the "too many arguments" trap you can pipe find into a while loop

```
#!/bin/bash -u
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*-run*_*.txt' |
{
    while read FNAME
    do
        N=${FNAME##*-run}
        N=${N%_*}
        DIR=r$N
        test -d $DIR || mkdir $DIR
        mv $FNAME $DIR/.
    done
}
```

Comment: I think the reason I ran into it in the first place is that I did not use ${i} with the extra {}. I havend tested this extensively asErik's solution did the trick. find is a really powerful thing however, I should probaly read a bit about it...