# Windows 7 Batch - Create subfolder, then find files with certain text in file name and move those files in the newly created subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, move

Tried my best searching for a solution but close to my need was this example which did not work. [Bash: Moving multiple files into subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882316/bash-moving-multiple-files-into-subfolders)

I am not a programmer so unable to create the batch file myself for Windows 7. Any help will be appreciated.

---

Needed code for a batch file that does the following:-

1. Searches the folder for all files that have "_F1" in the file name
2. Creates a subfolder named as "F1" where this file is located
3. Move all the files searched in step 1 to the folder "F1" created in step 2

Ideally, the batch file should execute from parent folder and should complete the 3 steps in all subfolders at least till 3 levels down the parent folder.

---

Thanks in Advance for any help.

---

I tried and came up with this. Works, but is very raw. Needs to be run manually from inside of each folder (100's of them)

```
MKDIR F1 

MKDIR F2 

DO 500

move *_F1*.* F1

move *_F2*.* F2

ENDDO
```

Comment: `batch` (as in Windows) or `bash`?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth sorry i meant batch file for windows

Comment: I follow what's being asked here, but it's worded in a slightly odd fashion.  It would help if you showed a treeview of the folder contents.  e.g. Start condition: folder1 contains boo, bar, baz, boo_f1, boo_f2, bar_f1, bar_f2, bar_f1_not; End condition: Want to have folder1 containing boo, bar, baz, bar_f1_not, folder2/; folder2 contains boo_f1, boo_f2, bar_f1, bar_f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d *.* ^| find /i "_F1"') do (
if not exist "%%~dpaF1" md "%%~dpaF1"
move "%%~fa" "%%~dpaF1")
```